# Custom theme error

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

the custom theme I'm using works on the local development server but not the production server which is a azure website. These are the errors I'm getting from orchards error logs.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ASP._Page_Themes_customtheme_Views_Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\Themes\customtheme\Views\Layout.cshtml:line 65 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass26.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAlterationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable1 parameters)
   at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
   at Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutAwareViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer)
   at Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutAwareViewEngine.LayoutView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: What's in that view on line 65?

Comment: @if (Model.Navigation != null)
{
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">